# Cannot add breakpoints whilst program is running

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022.  Please see the code below:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            int test = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                test = test + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

If I add a breakpoint before I leave the program to run, then it is reached.  Once I leave the program to run, then I cannot add any more breakpoints because of this error:

[image]

If I click 'No' then the same error appears a few seconds later.  If I click 'Yes' then this error appears:

[image]

If I add a `Console.WriteLine` like this then the behaviour is normal:

```
while (true)
{
    string test = "test";
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    string tess2 = "test";
}
```

I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio and giving myself a new Windows profile, which has not helped. This appears to happen with all app types e.g. MVC, Console etc and both VB.NET and C#.  My bigger apps are not running properly because of this problem.  Is there anything else I can try? Are there any more detailed logs I can look at?

Comment: The first loop is a closed one as it never breaks out, so the debugger has no chance to interrupt it.

Comment: @OldBoy, I don't understand what you mean.  The problem is with Visual Studio rather than the code.

Comment: you have an uncontrolled loop. set the breakpoints first then run.

Comment: @Daniel A. White, I am seeing the errors regardless of where I put the breakpoints in the bigger projects.  I just included the code above for demo purposes.

Comment: There is no problem with Visual Studio. In your code you have the following `            while(true)
            {
                test = test + 1;
            }
' and that loop will just cycle round for ever without allowing the debugger to interrupt. So that is why it does not work for you. You need a break in the code to allow the debugger to get control.

Comment: try using the pause button instead of trying to set break points. its tricky when a process is just spinning

Comment: @Daniel A. White, if I click 'break all' then I see the same behaviour.  None of my apps will run properly.

Comment: You say that none of your apps will run properly. You need to provide more information, as we cannot guess what the other code is doing.

Comment: What version of .Net and VS are you running? Are you running in Debug?Breakpoints work fine in the posted example for me, so my guess would be something in your environment. Antivirus? weird VS install? A VM might be useful for trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JonasH, I am using .NET Core 3.1.  The strange behaviour occurs in VS 2019 and VS 2022.

Comment: I tested it(Run the application and add breakpoints) using .NET Core 3.1 in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.9.2 without error. Did you do any settings or steps?

Comment: @Hui Liu-MSFT, it happens with all languages; frameworks and project types.  vs 2019 and vs2022 affected.  My other PC works as expected.

Comment: Based on your description, it should work. Maybe there are some settings that affect it. You could try the following troubleshooting steps: 1. Reset Visual Studio settings (go to Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings) 2. You can do this by deleting the .vs file in the solution directory folder to clear the solution cache. Please make sure to close Visual Studio before deleting this folder. 3. Try temporarily disabling any third-party extensions or antivirus/firewall software to see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Hui Liu-MSFT, I have tried all you suggested.  The problem goes away if I downgrade to .NET Framework (any version) or upgrade to .NET8.0 (.NET 6.0 has the problem).  Very strange.

Comment: Since I can't reproduce the issue, I'm not sure what the problem is. May be due to some code and settings. You could try to use a new user profile on your original machine and see if the issue persists when using Visual Studio under the new profile.  If necessary, consider uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio to see if the problem persists.